# Phonegap/Cordova : "pickContact" returns nothing on Windows Phone

Tags: cordova, windows-phone-8, phonegap-plugins

I am working on a phonegap application where user can select phone number or email from mobile's contact book. I am using contacts plugin for achieving this which is working on android but on windows phone 8 it render me to the contact book but after selecting any contact returns nothing (checked by putting an alert), even not giving any error. Basically I need to select contact to send sms/email. I am using following code:

```
$('.select-contact').bind('click', function () {
    navigator.contacts.pickContact(function(contact){
        alert(JSON.stringify(contact)); // not getting this alert on WP
        if (device.platform == 'Win32NT') {
            // need to write specific code for WP
        } else {
            sendSMS(contact.phoneNumbers[0].value); // checked this is not working on WP
        }
    },function(err){
        alert('Error: ' + err);
    });
});
```

http://plugins.cordova.io/#/package/org.apache.cordova.contacts

Is there any way to achieve this without creating a custom page. Any suggestion will be helpful.

Thanks in advance
Jaya